# Databases: Foreign key duplicates

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm trying to understand something about the foreign key of a database.
I couldn't find a clear answer for this.

The definition of a foreign key goes something like this,

**"Foreign key is a field or a group of fields in a table that refers to the primary key of another table"**
OK I get that.

Then we learn about types of relationships we can have among tables using foreign keys.
In **one-to-many(1:M)** and **many-to-many(M:N)** relationships, there are duplicates in the foreign key.

But how can this be?

**If a foreign key refers to a primary key and a primary key can't have duplicates, how can a foreign key can?**

I'm confused.
Can someone please explain this to me?

**Note** - I'm expecting a common answer, not a DBMS specific one.

Comment: It's hard to know where you got confused.  If two rows in the referencing table have the same value for the foreign key, it means they are referencing the same row in the referenced table.

Comment: @WalterMitty Ah I get it now. I think I know where I went wrong. See English isn't my first language. Everywhere I looked they used the word 'reference' when talking about foreign key and then 'relate' when talking about relationships. My definition of 'relate' isn't the same as 'reference'. If they had used 'reference' in relationship definitions like you did, I would have understood it. Thank you so much.

Comment: This covers up a deeper confusion in much of the literature.  "Relationships" as in the Entity-Relationship model, are not at the same level of abstraction as foreign keys in a "relational" model.  In fact,  foreign keys are completely unnecessary in a pure ER model.  Add to that the fact that most ERD diagrams are in fact depicting a relational model and not an ER model,  and you have the basis for massive confusion among native English spreakers, never mind someone who is struggling with English.

Answer (score 1):

**For example:**

There is an employee table with a primary key column called EmployeeID.  There is also a foreign key called SupervisorID, which references a different row in the same table.

Two employees work for the same supervisor.  They will have different values in the EmployeeID field, but the same value in the SupervisorID field.

This example uses a reference back to the same table,  but the concept is the same when the foreign key references a different table.